# How to provide autocomplete hints, similar to dataclass and sqlalchemy DeclarativeMeta?

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to implement a decorator or base class that obtains the list of fields in the declared class and adds to it a constructor that takes arguments corresponding to these fields. Similar to how `@dataclass` or SQLAlchemy's `declarative_base` works.

My question is - how do I get PyCharm and other IDEs to recognize and suggest autocompletion for this constructor.

For example, if I write this code:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: int
    baz: str

Foo([caret is here])
```

and press command-P (Parameter Info), PyCharm will show a tooltip with `bar:int, baz:str`. Additionally, if I make a mistake in the parameter name, it will warn me. So basically, it seems that PyCharm "knows" that the `@dataclass` decorator adds an `__init__` method and its exact signature.

How do I get it to do that for my decorator?

Comment: I am only speculating here: mypy has a plugin for [dataclass](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py) so i would also guess that PyCharm has a special case for that particular decorator. If my assumption is correct, you can't achieve what you want. Why do you need a custom decorator? Maybe you can somehow reuse the existing dataclass.

Comment: Write a docstring for the dataclass.

Comment: @Wombatz Then it also has a special case for SQLAlchemy, because it works the same way for that library. Maybe I could add another decorator either on top of or below `@dataclass`. It would be quite hackish, though.

Comment: Dataclass is a special case in PyCharm: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/python-psi-impl/src/com/jetbrains/python/codeInsight/stdlib/PyDataclassTypeProvider.kt

Comment: @user2235698 Well, that's annoying. Is SQLAlchemy also a special case? I couldn't find a similar file for it.

Comment: @msasha right, sqlalchemy support is PyCharm Pro feature and hence it is not presented in the open sourced repository